# An ellipse whose one focus is $(4,3)$ passes through $(1,2)$ and equation of tangent at $(1,2)$ is $x+y-3=0$. Find length of minor axis, eccentricity.

Tags: contest-math, conic-sections

> An ellipse whose one focus is $(4,3)$ passes through $(1,2)$ and equation of tangent at $(1,2)$ is $x+y-3=0$. If the abscissa of centre of ellipse is $7$, find the length of minor axis and eccentricity of the ellipse.

**My Attempt:**

Let the centre be $(7,k)$

If one focus is $(4,3)$, the other focus is $(10,2k-3)$

Can we say the equation of tangent is $y-k=m(x-7)\pm\sqrt{a^2m^2+b^2}$, where $a,b$ are the lengths of semi-major and minor axis.

From given equation, $m=-1$ and intercept $=3$. So, we'll get one equation in $a,b,k$

Also, sum of focal distances of a point is equal to length of major axis. So, from here we'll get one equation in $a,k$

But we have three variables, so, need three equations.

Not able to proceed ahead.

Comment: Use that the ellipse goes thru $(1,2)$ to get another equation for $a,b$

Comment: If the abscissa of center is $7$, then the abscissa of second focus is $10$. The second focus also lies on the line passing through $P=(1,2)$ and through $(2,5)$ (the reflection of the first focus about the normal at $P$). Hence the second focus is $(10,29)$.

Comment: The normal at $P(1,2)$ bisects the angle between lines $PF$ and $PF',$ where $F, F'$ are foci. This is a caracteristic property of ellipse. The normal has equation $x-y+1=0.$   If  $F(4,3),$ then the line
$$\overline{PF}:\quad x-3y+5=0 $$
The point symmetric to $F$ with respect to the normal is $F_1(2,5).$ The focus $F'$ lies on $\overline{PF_1}.$

Comment: @Intelligentipauca can you post that hint as an answer so that I could close this thread? Thanks.

Comment: "Can we say the equation of tangent is $y-k=m(x-7)\pm\sqrt{a^2m^2+b^2}$" I don't think we can because the equation of this ellipse is not necessarily of the form $\frac{(x-7)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2}=1$. Considering $y-k=m(x-7)\pm\sqrt{a^2m^2+b^2}$ should mean that you are assuming that the equation of the ellipse is of the form $\frac{(x-7)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2}=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the abscissa of center is $7$, then the abscissa of second focus is $10$. The second focus also lies on the line passing through $P=(1,2)$
and through $(2,5)$ (the reflection of the first focus about the normal at
$P$). Hence the second focus is $(10,29)$.